# Getting entire row in mindmup's editable-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I'm using mindmup's editable table [github.com/mindmup/editable-table](http://github.com/mindmup/editable-table). I need to be able to post an entire row to another URL. I'm new to javascript, so I'm just trying to get over this bump. When you have one row for the table, it works fine, but when you have multiple rows, it always submits the last row. I'm trying to get the data for all the cell in entire row. My code is [Code](https://gist.github.com/waco001/66b12c6ebba6af61d60f)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the entire table into JSON using the tableToJSON jquery widget from the [following](http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/) link.

I hope this works for you.